# Changing datastructure to create correct bar graph in ggplot

Tags: r, excel, ggplot2, data-structures

I would like to make a graph in R, which I managed to make in excel. It is a bargraph with species on the x-axis and the log number of observations on the y-axis. My current data structure in R is not suitable (I think) to make this graph, but I do not know how to change this (in a smart way).

I have (amongst others) a column 'camera_site' (site 1, site2..), 'species' (agouti, paca..), 'count'(1, 2..), with about 50.000 observations.

I tried making a dataframe with  a column 'species" (with 18 species) and a column with 'log(total observation)' for each species ([see dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XS3jl.png)) But then I can only make a point graph.

this is how I would like the graph to look: 
[desired graph made in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8T2W.jpg)

Comment: Your dataset seems to have the correct format. Try this `ggplot(dt, aes(VRM_species, log_obs_count_vrm)) + geom_col()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data seems to be in the correct format from what I can tell from your screenshot.
The minimum amount of code you would need to get a plot like that would be the following, assuming your data.frame is called `df`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(VRM_species, log_obs_count_vrm)) +
  geom_col()
```

Many people intuitively try `geom_bar()`, but `geom_col()` is equivalent to `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`, which you would use if you've pre-computed observations and don't need ggplot to do the counting for you.
But you could probably decorate the plot a bit better with some additions:

```
ggplot(df, aes(VRM_species, log_obs_count_vrm)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "Species") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = expression("Log"[10]*" Observations"),
                     expand = c(0,0,0.1,0)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

Of course, you could customize the theme anyway you would like.

Groetjes